# Permission Error in Android Version 13 for Uploading xlsx file in Android 13

Tags: flutter, permissions, xlsx, filepicker, android-13

In my project, I am using the file_picker package for picking Excel(xlsx) files. It still works perfectly in Android 12 and below. However, when I changed my app's target version to 33 as per Play Store Policy, which is Android 13, it stops working and gives me an error:

```
PlatformException: PlatfomException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)
```

I have included all the required permissions in my manifest file, but I am still encountering this error. Additionally, in the app info, I am not seeing any requested permission for storage. This issue is specific to Android 13.